# How to access values of elements of std::set in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I was implementing a set of arrays in C++, and wanted to track the values in it using gdb so I created a breakpoint after the data is initialized. The gdb in Vscode is fired up, but all I see for the set is a myriad of pointers. I see no values to follow. I know that sets are implemented using red-black trees so the pointers originate from there but there should  be a way to see the values.
[image: Vscode screen shot]

So I hop onto [Online gdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) to check whether this is a gdb thing. But fortunately it was able to show its element

[image: Online gdb]

Environment details :
Gdb version (My local) : GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3.1
Gdb version (Online gdb) :  gdb 7.11.1

G++ versionv(My local) : g++ (GCC) 9.2.0
G++ version (Online gdb) : g++ (GCC) 5.4.1

So what am I doing wrong? Or does vscode isn't able to show the values?

**EDIT**
So I tried using gdb from the command lines

```
15          for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
(gdb) print s
$1 = {_M_t = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::array<int, 2> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::array<int, 2> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <std::_Rb_tree_key_compare<std::less<std::array<int, 2> > >> = {
        _M_key_compare = {<std::binary_function<std::array<int, 2>, std::array<int, 2>, bool>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}}, <std::_Rb_tree_header> = {_M_header = {_M_color = std::_S_red, _M_parent = 0x181610,
          _M_left = 0x181a40, _M_right = 0x181b60}, _M_node_count = 5}, <No data fields>}}}
(gdb)
```

For anyone wondering how I generate my set

```
int n,m; cin>> n>>m;
set <array<int,2>> s;
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    int a; cin>>a;
    s.insert({a,i});
}
```

So how do I access my values?

Comment: You really should mention what version of gdb you are using and the version used at the online compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I added the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my answer after loads of google searches. The answer was pretty-printers, I'm on windows so I had to install MinGW but mine didn't have the ability to support python scripts and also were lacking libstdc++-v3 library.

---

1. Download [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds) which supports python scripts and has the libstdc++-v3 library
2. Delete the old MinGW
3. Change your `PATH` in system environment variables
4. Restart
5. Check using command prompt `gdb --version`
6. Now in vscode change your `launch.json` and `task.json` to reflect the change in the location (if changed)